# Postgresql select until certain total amount is reached and lock

Tags: sql, postgresql, sum, window-functions, gaps-and-islands

I have a table of user batches. I only want to select until my amount total reaches a certain amount.

```
id  | user_id | balance | batch_id 
----|---------|-------- |--------
 1  | 1       |   2     | 1
 2  | 2       |   15    | 2
 3  | 1       |   8     | 3
 4  | 1       |   5     | 4 
 5  | 2       |   7     | 5
 6  | 1       |   1     | 6
 7  | 2       |   5     | 7
```

Consider the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM tb_batch_user WHERE user_id = 1 ORDER BY batch_id asc
```

The result of query is:

```
    id  | user_id | balance | batch_id 
    ----|---------|-------- |--------
     1  | 1       |   2     | 1
     3  | 1       |   8     | 3
     4  | 1       |   5     | 4 
     6  | 1       |   1     | 6
```

I want to do a select on the table until the balance total is 6. **Then only ids 1, 2 should be returned:**

```
    id  | user_id | balance | batch_id 
    ----|---------|-------- |--------
     1  | 1       |   2     | 1
     3  | 1       |   8     | 3
```

Another example with balance total 1. **Then only ids 1 should be returned:**

```
    id  | user_id | balance | batch_id 
    ----|---------|-------- |--------
     1  | 1       |   2     | 1
```

Example with balance total 11. **Only ids 1,3,4 should be returned:**

```
    id  | user_id | balance | batch_id 
    ----|---------|-------- |--------
     1  | 1       |   2     | 1
     3  | 1       |   8     | 3
     4  | 1       |   5     | 4
```

So, after that I need to lock those lines with FOR UPDATE ex:

```
     SELECT * FROM tb_batch_user WHERE user_id = 1 ORDER BY batch_id asc FOR UPDATE
```

I tried with window function, but it doesn't allow lock (FOR UPDATE). Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am able to `select. . . for update` using window functions:

```
with inparms as (
  select 1 as user_id, 6 as target
), rtotal as (
  select t.id, i.target,
         sum(t.balance) over (partition by t.user_id
                                  order by t.id
                              rows between unbounded preceding
                                       and 1 preceding) as runbalance
    from tb_batch_user t
         join inparms i 
           on i.user_id = t.user_id
)
select t.*
  from rtotal r
       join tb_batch_user t
         on t.id = r.id
 where coalesce(r.runbalance, 0) < r.target
for update of t;
```

[Fiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=20daff3127a4c80f206a3baa5cbc1e28)

Comment: Hmm, [if the `balance` of the row with `id` `3` was `4` it includes the row with the `id` of `4`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=878052ce2ddf7614ec858c8ffa6627bf)... is that intended @KelvinSantiago?

Comment: Yes, it does. And I would imagine that means not to include the row with id `4` when the rows with `id` `1` and id `4` already add up to a sum `6`. But maybe the OP indeed wanted the "next" one row in such a case too.

Comment: @stickybit  You are correct.  That should be a straight `<`.  Thank you for catching that.

Comment: Working.  Would it have performance problems with a table with millions of records?

Comment: @KelvinSantiago  You need to run it to find out.  Provided that `user_id` is indexed, this should perform pretty well.  If it doesn't then you can change the `rtotal` CTE into a subquery.

Comment: @MikeOrganek Where I could do the sorting (order by) with distribution_id, and filter by other columns (where)

Comment: @KelvinSantiago  I do not see a `distribution_id` in your original question.  Do you want to `order by distribution_id` before or after you filter by the running `balance`?

Comment: @MikeOrganek Sorry, I meant batch_id. Example. SELECT * FROM tb_batch_user WHERE user_id = 1 and **another_field_1 = 10** ORDER BY batch_id asc

Comment: @KelvinSantiago  Add the `where` clause to the `rtotal` CTE.  Then change the `rtotal` CTE so that the window for `sum(balance)` is `order by t.batch_id` instead of `order by t.id`.

Answer (score 1):

are you looking for this?

```
with w0 as (
  select id, user_id, balance, batch_id,
     coalesce(lag(running_balance) over (partition by user_id order by batch_id asc), 0) running_balance 
  from (
      SELECT t.* ,
        sum(balance) over (partition by user_id order by batch_id asc) running_balance
      FROM tb_batch_user t 
      --where t.user_id = 1
  ) x 
)
select * from w0
where running_balance < 6
```

PS: you can add user_id as where clause. see comment

for locking,

```
select * from tb_batch_user tb
where tb.id in (select w0.id from w0 where running_balance < 6)
for update
```

Comment: Hmm, that doesn't seem to lock anything, when `FOR UPDATE` is added. It doesn't throw an error though.

Comment: for update and query is working. I'll evaluate the performance of this query with explain.

Comment: @Derviş Kayımbaşıoğlu    there is some way not to go through the entire table, that is, stop until the value found. In query SELECT t.* ,
        sum(balance) over (partition by user_id order by batch_id asc) running_balance
      FROM tb_batch_user t

Answer (score 1):

Here is an approach using window functions:

```
select id, balance, user_id, batch_id
from (
    select t.*, 
        sum(balance) over(partition by user_id order by id) sum_balance
    from mytable t
    where user_id = 1
) t
where sum_balance - balance < 6
```

You want a cumulative balance until the first one that equals or exceeds the threshold. For this, you can just use a window `sum()`.

You can change the inequality condition to the threshold value that you like. You can also change (or remove) the filtering on `user_id` in the subquery.

We can easily implement the same logic with a subquery, that would support `for update`:

```
select *
from mytable t
where user_id = 1 and (
    select coalesce(sum(balance), 0)
    from mytable t1
    where t1.user_id = t.user_id and t1.id < t.id
) < 6
for update
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=fe6cbc2e429577cd45e018d0f8086bc2)**:

```
id | balance | user_id
-: | ------: | ------:
 1 |       2 |       1
 3 |       8 |       1
```

Comment: Adding `FOR UPDATE` to it throws the error "FOR UPDATE is not allowed with window functions".

Comment: @stickybit: good point, thank you. I updated my answer with the same solution as a subquery.

Comment: And I can confirm that your edit seems to do the locking right.

Comment: Hmm but another thing: Hmm, [if the `balance` of the row with `id` `3` was `4` it includes the row with the `id` of `4` and `6`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=bef8308b981a5c95545e84ed37d58cc2)... The row with `id` `4` might be intended by the OP in such a case, but I cannot imagine they then also want the row with `id` `6`.

Comment: @GMB not workimg, try with amount 11, only ids 1,3,4 should be returned

Comment: @KelvinSantiago: ok, this clarifies the logic you want (you might want to add that information to your question as well). I updated my answer.

Comment: @KelvinSantiago: thanks. Do my revised queries work for you?

Comment: @GMB Yes! Working, now i'll try with order by, and test performance. Do you see problem with this query in table with million of records?

Comment: @GMB I made an insert with more than 1 million records, and it is very slow. I waited more than 10min and did not return, even with index.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `(user_id, batch_id)` is a key, you can use correlated subqueries to avoid window functions. The outer subquery gets the minimal `batch_id` where the sum of `balance` reaches or exceeds `6` for the given user id. That sum is fetched in the inner one.

```
SELECT *
       FROM tb_batch_user bu1
            WHERE bu1.user_id = 1
                  AND bu1.batch_id <= (SELECT min(bu2.batch_id) batch_id
                                              FROM tb_batch_user bu2
                                              WHERE bu2.user_id = bu1.user_id
                                                    AND (SELECT sum(bu3.balance)
                                                                FROM tb_batch_user bu3
                                                                WHERE bu3.user_id = bu2.user_id
                                                                      AND bu3.batch_id <= bu2.batch_id) >= 6)
       FOR UPDATE;
```

With the [`pgrowlocks` extension](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/pgrowlocks.html) installed, we can check that the right rows are locked.

```
SELECT *
       FROM pgrowlocks('tb_batch_user');
```

returns:

```
 locked_row | locker   | multi | xids       | modes          | pids
------------+----------+-------+------------+----------------+---------
 (0,1)      | 10847645 | f     | {10847645} | {"For Update"} | {11996}
 (0,3)      | 10847645 | f     | {10847645} | {"For Update"} | {11996}
```